# defaultActiveKey prop of antd tabs not working in Array.map

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am trying to set the `defaultActiveKey` for **antd tabs**. I tried like this:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import { Row, Tabs } from "antd";

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const MyComponent = (props) => {

  const [tabs, setTabs] = useState([]);
  const defaultTab = 'tab2';

  useEffect(() => {
    const tabsData = [
      { name: "Tab 1", key: "tab1" },
      { name: "Tab 2", key: "tab2" },
      { name: "Tab 3", key: "tab3" }
    ];
    setTabs(tabsData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Row>
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey={defaultTab}>
         
          {
            tabs.map(({name, key}) => (
              <TabPane tab={name} key={key}>
                Content of {name}
              </TabPane>
            ))
          }
        </Tabs>
      </Row>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I want to set **tab2** as the `defaultActiveKey` but it isn't working. But it's working when I do this:

```
<Tabs defaultActiveKey={defaultTab}>
  <TabPane tab={tabs[0].name} key={tabs[0].key}>
    <SomeComponent/>
  </TabPane>
  <TabPane tab={tabs[1].name} key={tabs[1].key}>
    <SomeComponent/>
  </TabPane>
  <TabPane tab={tabs[2].name} key={tabs[2].key}>
    <SomeComponent/>
  </TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Thank you @Ajeet Shah
Now i updated the question with my scenario. Sorry I couldn't able to frame the question properly before. Please see my answer below

Comment: If `tabsData` is a constant, you don't need to keep it in state. You can define constants outside your component definition, or even in a separate file and import it from there. Then you don't even need to do its `.length>0` check.

Comment: It's not a constant in my case. Actually tabs data is a dynamic data. @Ajeet Shah

Answer (score 1):

check the length of the `tabs` in return statement

```
 return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {tabs.length > 0 && (
        <Tabs defaultActiveKey={defaultTab}>
          {tabs.map(({ name, key }) => (
            <TabPane tab={name} key={key}>
              Content of {name}
            </TabPane>
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
)
```